# Can't return Node pointer

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ linked list class.  I have implemented and tested insert and print.  However, I can't seem to return a Node pointer for delete.  I get these errors when I try delete:

```
    Node.h:11: error: expected unqualified-id before "delete"
    Node.h:11: error: abstract declarator `Node*' used as declaration
    Node.h:11: error: expected `;' before "delete"

    Node.cpp:21: error: expected unqualified-id before "delete"
    Node.cpp:21: error: expected init-declarator before "delete"
    Node.cpp:21: error: expected `,' or `;' before "delete"

    make.exe: *** [Node.o] Error 1

    Execution terminated
```

Here's my code:

Node.h

```
    #ifndef Node_H
    #define Node_H


    class Node{
          int data;
          Node* next;

    public:
           Node(int data);       
           void insert(int d);
           Node* delete(int d);
           void printOut(void);
    };

    #endif
```

Node.cpp

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "Node.h"

    Node::Node(int d){
          data = d;
          next = NULL;
          }

    void Node::insert(int d){

          Node* n = this;
          Node* current = new Node(d);

          while(n->next != NULL){
                  n = n->next;                   
                  }

          n->next = current;
          }

    Node* Node::delete(int d){

          Node* head = this;
          Node* n = this;

          if (n->data = null){
             return n;
             }

          if (n->data == d){
             return n->next;
             }

          while(n->next != NULL){

          if (n->next->data == d){
             n->next = n->next->next;
             return head;
             }

          n = n->next;

          }

        return head;

        }

    void Node::printOut(void){

         Node* n = this;

         while(n->next != NULL){
                      printf("%d ->", n->data);
                       n = n->next;                   
                       }

         printf("%d \n", n->data);

         }
```

main:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cstdlib>

    #include "Node.h"
    using namespace std;

    int main (void){
        int i = 0;

        Node* root = new Node(111);
        Node* result;

        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            root->insert(i);
            } 

        root->printOut();

        result = root->delete(5);

        result->printOut();

        printf("Hello j \n");

        getchar();
        delete[] root; 
        return 0;   
    }
```

Comment: Also, use an IDE or emacs so that you can see the reserved keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The token `delete` is a [reserved keyword in  C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). Pick a different name for the function (like `remove`).

Answer (score 4):

`delete` is c++ keyword, you can't use it as function name `Node* Node::delete(int d)`
you can change your function name to `Node* Node::remove(int d)`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Answer (score 4):

The previous posters have told you the issue - that `delete` is a reserved C++ keyword and you can't use it for your function name.

I want to point out a few other issues with your code:

1. First of all, you call `delete[] root;` but that is wrong... `root` is not allocated by `new[]` but with `new` and so, must be deallocated with `delete` and not `delete[]`.
2. Secondly, you are not deleting any of the nodes in the list. That may be OK for this little program (the memory will be returned to the O/S when your program exits) you are still leaking memory. Every pointer that you allocate with `new` must be deallocated with `delete` and every pointer you allocate with `new[]` must be deallocated with `delete[]`. Remember, `new` and `delete` must come in pairs.
3. Last but not least: Look at what happens when you try to call 'printOut' on a list composed only of a single root. You will see that nothing gets printed. For a hint as to why this happens, look at the code in printOut() and speak out the logic of the code to yourself, as if you are a computer executing it.

Good luck.